# Hello everyone I want to unroot my phone I has buy this phone YU YU phoria 5010A and I got it rooted can anyone help

Tags: unrooting

My phone is rooted by apps called super Su plz help me my play store didn't open

Answer (score 1):

Open SuperSU > Settings > Cleanup > Full unroot.

Reboot your device once done.